# A-Frame: how to animate Orbit-Controls?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm playing with [Orbit controller](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/orbit-controls/) component by ngokevin and I have some issue with animations.

My context is simple: I have a 3d scene with different elements that, once get clicked, should move the camera to "look at them".

So far I've been able to dynamically change the orbit-controls `target`, and somehow it works:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent( 'mytest-click', {
  schema: {
    active: { type: "boolean" }
  },
  init: function () {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    el.addEventListener( 'click', function ( evt ) {
      // Calculate real position
      var targetPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
      targetPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( evt.target.object3D.matrixWorld );
      var cameraPosition = document.querySelector( '#camera' ).getAttribute( 'position' );

      targetPosition.y -= cameraPosition.y;

      var currOrbit = document.querySelector( '#camera' ).getAttribute( 'orbit-controls' );
      currOrbit.target = targetPosition;
      document.querySelector( '#camera' ).setAttribute( 'orbit-controls', currOrbit );
    } );
  }
});
```

My problem is that I can't animate it.. I've tried with animation like `animation__test="property: orbit-controls.target; ..."` but it doesn't work..

Any idea?

Comment: Try using world positions (`camera.updateMatrixWorld(); camera.getWorldPosition(worldPosVec)`). Make sure to pause the orbit controls before animating, or animate a container.

Comment: Tryed, but when i attach/reenable orbit (tryed both) there are like a flickr in the camera.. now im testing this way: https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls
If it works, i'll probably ending making an aframe component (starting from your component, orbit-controls)

Comment: ant news on this?

Comment: @Magico yep, i somehow edited the Orbit-controls; See my answer to the question. (sorry) No time now to clean the code and implement all the methods, but it works somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adapting the [Orbit-controls plugin](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/orbit-controls) to use [Camera Controls Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-controls).

ya'll be warned: that's probably the ugliest and dirties way to do that, I just adapedt the methods I needed. Use at your own risk.

[That's the link to the repo](https://github.com/Strae/aframe-camera-controls)